# Check box creation doesn't work in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("div").append($(document.createElement("input")).attr({
                         'id':    'post_category',
                         'value': 'item',
                        'type':  'checkbox','checked': true
                     }));
```

I am trying to create checkbox with checked but ie7 display nothing. while other browsers displays checkbox as checked. **How to display checkbox selected in ie7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code works in other browser**

```
$("div").append("<input id='post_category' value='item' type='checkbox' checked='checked'>");
```

**Solution To insert checkbox as checked in ie7**

```
var category_checkbox = $("<input>").attr({'name' : 'post_category[]' , 'id' : 'post_category' , 'type' : 'checkbox' , 'value' : '1'});

$("div").append(category_checkbox);

category_checkbox.attr({'checked' : 'checked'})
```

***IE7 wont accept checked attribute while inserting elements. so once we append checkbox refer that checkbox and set attribute as checked.***

Answer (score 4):

Any reason you can't do it like this:

```
$("div").append("<input id='post_category' value='item' type='checkbox' checked='checked'>");
```

You could construct it dynamically, as per your original intention:

```
$("div").append($("<input>").attr({
                     'id':    'post_category',
                     'value': 'item',
                    'type':  'checkbox','checked': true
                 }));
```

As per this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ReErJ/2/

I also notice that in your code you have

```
'checked': true
```

That should be

```
'checked': 'checked'
```

Comment: Ur answer not works in ie7 browser. I found the solution refer my answer. Thaks for ur help

Answer (score 3):

Try to set *'checked': 'checked'*, not true

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code you posted into a new page, and I get 2 checkboxes in IE7. Perhaps you have an issue somewhere else in your code?